# How to get an object from an asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**Question**
How to get an object from an asynchronous method?

**Description**
I am trying to do a similar project.
Link to the project - [Link // github.com](https://github.com/unpub777/PersonalPortal/blob/master/DBRepository/Repositories/BlogRepository.cs) ;
  
I try to repeat the method - `GetPosts (int index, int pageSize, string tag = null)`.

```
public async Task<Page<Post>> GetPosts(int index, int pageSize, string tag = null)
    {
        var result = new Page<Post>() { CurrentPage = index, PageSize = pageSize };

        using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = context.Posts.AsQueryable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag))
            {
                query = query.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName == tag));
            }

            result.TotalPages = await query.CountAsync();
            result.Records = await query.Include(p => p.Tags).Include(p => p.Comments).OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate).Skip(index * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I want to make a similar asynchronous method with an arbitrary request.
A query for example: `query = query.Where (p => p.ContactName.Contains (" Maria "));`.
    
I try to make a simple method:

```
public Customer GetCustomers ()
{
    Customer result = new Customer ();
 
    using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext (ConnectionString))
    {
      var query = context.Customers.AsQueryable ();
      query = query.Where (p => p.ContactName.Contains ("Maria")); //
      result = query as Customer;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The result in the string `query = query.Where (p => p.ContactName.Contains (" Maria "));` see picture.
 
**Question.**
How to make such a method asynchronous with the same or different request?

**Attempt number - 1. Result - does not work.**

```
public Task <Customer> GetCustomersTask ()
        {
            // Customer result = new Customer ();
 
            var result = new TaskCompletionSource <Customer> ();
 
            using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext (ConnectionString))
            {
                Task.Run (() =>
                {
                    var query = context.Customers.AsQueryable ();
                    query = query.Where (p => p.ContactName == "Maria");
 
                    result.SetResult (query as Customer);
                }
                );
            }
            return result.Task;
        }
```

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

---

### Update 1. ##

*According to the materials of the answer: Martin. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868420/6914750)*

I am using the method.

```
 public async Task <Customer> GetCustomerAsync ()
{
    Customer result = new Customer ();

    using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext (ConnectionString))
    {
      var query = context.Customers.AsQueryable ();
      query = query.Where (p => p.ContactName.Contains ("Maria")); //
      var results = await query.ToListAsync ();
      result = results.FirstOrDefault ();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I get an error:
*"IQueryable " does not contain a definition of "ToListAsync",
and could not find an available extension method "ToListAsync",
host type "IQueryable " as the first
argument (possibly using directive or assembly reference missing).*

**Picture-1**
[image]

---

### Update 2

Added by `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`.
Now the class namespace has the form:
`using DBRepository.Interfaces;

using Models;

using System;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Error (see **Update-1**):
`"IQueryable" does not contain a definition of "ToListAsync", and could not find an available extension method "ToListAsync", host type "IQueryable" as the first argument (possibly using directive or assembly reference missing).`
has disappeared.

**Description.**
I am running debugging.
I get into the string `var results = await query.ToListAsync ();`(of class`ICustomerRepositoryAnsw.GetCustomersTask1 ()`);
I press F11.
I get into the string `string result =" ";` (of the class `TestAnsw` method `GetCustomersTask_Test()` (this method calls `ICustomerRepositoryAnsw.GetCustomersTask1()`).
Result: debugging does not execute the string `result = results.FirstOrDefault ();` and `return result;`

**Question.**
1. Why are the lines `result = results.FirstOrDefault ();` and `return result;` not executed?

**Picture-1** 
[image]

**Picture-2** 
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not simply use async/await pattern instead of the ```TaskCompletionSource```. There is a well written answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: @Martin **1.** `Is there a reason why you are not simply use async/await pattern instead of the TaskCompletionSource.`  Is that a question?
No. I'm just trying to figure out how to make a method that works asynchronously and returns the result I need.
 **2.** I am studying your link.

Comment: Sorry I missed the question mark it was a question. I posted a possible answer. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: ```GetCustomersTask1``` needs to be awaited because its an async method. You can see this in "Raw View" that you only have the ```Task``` here. [See documentation of await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good documentation on template the `async/await` - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)(I already wrote in the comment above).
 As a summary, I can say:
 `Task <T>` or `async` **NOT** makes the method asynchronous.
 Only the `await` keyword makes the method asynchronous.

So if you want your method to be run non-blocking you must use asynchronous API/Framework calls to the EntityFramework.

```
public Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync ()
{
    Customer result = new Customer ();

    using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext (ConnectionString))
    {
      var query = context.Customers.AsQueryable ();
      query = query.Where(p => p.ContactName.Contains ("Maria")); //
      result = query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Looks asynchronous but is **not**.

But if you use the extensions method `.ToListAsync()`

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync ()
{
    Customer result = new Customer ();

    using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext (ConnectionString))
    {
      var query = context.Customers.AsQueryable ();
      query = query.Where (p => p.ContactName.Contains ("Maria")); //
      var results = await query.ToListAsync();
      result = results?.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can call this implementation via:

```
var customer = await YourClass.GetCustomerAsync();
```

[Then it will run non-blocking async.](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/ef6/fundamentals/async)

[EntityFramework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/async)

Comment: I do not understand your answer well.  
**1.** Do you mean that I need to use the `Framework` application?
**2.** Have you noticed that I use `.net-core`,` entity-framework-core`?
Or your solution for `.net-Framework` ?
**3.** In the line `var results = await query.ToListAsync ()`
I get an error:
`"IQueryable <Customer>" does not contain a definition of “ToListAsync”,
and could not find an available extension method "ToListAsync",
host type "IQueryable <Customer>" as the first
argument (possibly using using directive or assembly reference).`
see `Update-1`

Comment: 1. Use the ```[...]Async()``` Methods of EF or other SDKs. 2. yes, therefore I also updated my answer with a direct link to EF Core. 3. Maybe you have to add a ```using``` for this extension method

Comment: see `Update-2.`
Added by `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`.
The error has disappeared.
Result: debugging does not execute the string `result = results.FirstOrDefault ();` and `return result;`

**Question.**
** 1. ** Why are the lines `result = results.FirstOrDefault ();` and `return result;` not executed?

Comment: I updated your answer.
I made corrections that I think will make your answer more understandable (sound better).
I do not know English well, so I apologize if my interpretation of the answer seems incorrect to you. If you think your interpretation of the answer is better, then you should probably leave your answer option.